# Compile error (preprocessing error) while using gcc on osx on __has_feature

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, grpc

I am trying to compile grpc using gcc on an M1 osx. I get the following error:

```
missing binary operator before token "("  #if !(defined(__has_feature) && __has_feature(cxx_thread_local))
```

Any idea how this can be resolved?